# Curl https inside docker container returns timeout

Tags: docker, networking, debian, containers

Inside a docker container when i run

`curl -v https://application.company.com` i always get a timeout after around 5 minutes.

`curl -v http://application.company.com` returns `301 Moved Permanently`

Comment: well, your webserver redirects http:// traffic to httpS:// but doesn't seem to listen on tht port. This is unrelated to *programming* (so off-topic for [so]), you probably should ask on [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com)